# Footer in DHTMLX with Dynamic Loading

Tags: footer, dhtmlx, dynamic-loading

I've had enough of search for how to attach the Footer on DHTMLX Grids that is working with Dynamic Loading of SmartRendering.

My method that calculates the Totals is the following:

```
function calculateTotals(){
        var test = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < myGrid.getRowsNum(); i++) {
            test += myGrid.cells2(i,8).getValue()!= "" ? parseInt(myGrid.cells2(i,8).getValue()) : 0;
        }

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = test;
    }
```

This is called on event onGridReconstructed.

The footer declaration is this:

```
myGrid.attachFooter("Rows:,, <div id='totalRows'>0</div>, , , ,Totals , , <div id='test'>0</div>
```

The fact is that this works with some data, but not with large amounts of data, which presupposes that there is an incompatibility between this type of footer and Dynamic Loading of SmartRendering.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not available to get the value of a cell until this cell is loaded to the client-side and rendered, so it is not available to iterate through all the rows in case of using the dynamic loading mode.